# Confusion in notations of number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

In several materials I saw the notation for complete residue system as follows

$\mathbb{Z}_n=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots, n-1\}$

But in some other materials/ in the same material, It says that the above notation is wrong and has to be represented as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Which I have to follow, the reason for my doubt is the notation I used first is used mostly in school materials. If its not correct, than what $\mathbb{Z}_n$ actually mean?

How can I represent complete co-prime residue system? Is it $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ or $\mathbb{Z}^*/ n?$

And finally how can I interpret $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? Is it $\mathbb{Z} - n\mathbb{Z}$ . If it is, then what $n\mathbb{Z}$ mean?

Comment: I have never come across $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z_n$ before. Do you have any context for that?

Comment: Sorry.. pls refresh. Hurry mistake.

Comment: $Z/nZ$ is the favoured notation since $Z_p$ is also used by the p-adic numbers. $Z_n$ is sometimes used for the cyclic group but usually shouldnt cause confusion. $Z_n^{x}$ is fine for complete co prime residues.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n \cong \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 2):

The notation mostly depends upon whether the author of the text is planning on dealing with [$p$-adic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) numbers or not. If the author is not planning on discussing them (as is the case in many elementary number theory or group theory texts), then the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ seems to be fairly common. When $p$-adic numbers are around, however, that notation generally means something different (which I won't discuss here for fear of being off topic, unless you leave a comment below asking for a description).

The other notation (and what probably many number theorists would consider to be the "better" notation) is to use $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. This notation implies that we are looking at the numbers [modulo n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), and the reason we do this has to do with some mathematical structures called "[quotient rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)." $n\mathbb{Z}$ means all integer multiples of the number $n$. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ means that we are declaring all multiples of $n$ to be equivalent, which is another way of saying that we are taking the numbers modulo $n$.

You would probably want to represent the co-primes as $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$.

Comment: So, $n\mathbb{Z}=\{0,n,2n,\cdots \}$ ?

Comment: Yup, $n\mathbb{Z}=\{...,-2n,-n,0,n,2n,...,\}$.

Comment: Then how can I write $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ in terms of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\mathbb{Z}$? What I mean is if $A,B$ are sets, then what $A/B$ means?

Comment: If it is $\mathbb{Z}-n\mathbb{Z}$ then I can't get $0$ in resulting set.

Comment: To understand this, I would recommend reading a little bit about group theory, in particular quotient groups. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ means that we are taking everything in $n\mathbb{Z}$ to be equivalent to zero. This means that if two integers differ from each other by a multiple of $n$ (so, $a=b+nk$), then we say $a\equiv b$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. This is actually just another way of saying that we are doing modular arithmetic. Again, reading about quotient groups should help the confusion. It is NOT $\mathbb{Z}-n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: A *coset* of $n{\bf Z}$ is a set of the form $a+n{\bf Z}$, by which is meant $\{\,a,a\pm n,a\pm2n,\dots\,\}$. $n{\bf Z}$ has exactly $n$ distinct cosets, namely, $0+n{\bf Z},1+n{\bf Z},\dots,n-1+n{\bf Z}$. You can add, subtract, and multiply two cosets, and get a coset: $(a+n{\bf Z})+(b+n{\bf Z})$ is the coset containing $a+b$, similarly for the difference and product. ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$ is the notation for the set whose elements are these $n$ cosets, with this way of doing the arithmetical operations.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the group of integers, modulo $n$, under addition. This is what we usually use when we use modular arithmetic and residue classes, etc. So $\mathbb{Z}_n = \{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}, ... \overline{n-1}\}$.

Now $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an example of a quotient group. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = \{0+n\mathbb{Z}, 1+n\mathbb{Z},...,(n-1)+n\mathbb{Z}\}$, which can be naturally identified with $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

I'd assume the group of coprimes would be denoted $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$